# Распределение памяти в паттерне состояние

Tags: c#, unity3d, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется два разных состояния объекта. 
Проблема, а вернее вопрос такой. Выходит что каждый раз , когда я переключаюсь между состояниями, создается и инициализируется новый класс, что естественно требует времени и средств. 
Можно ли это избежать? Т.е возможно ли резервировать память под эти классы, чтобы они каждый раз заново не создавались, а просто получали ссылку? Или в этом нет смысла?

```
 public void setValues(string ground_checker_name, string character_name,string player_name, string rot_name)
{

    tricksnew = new TricksNew( ground_checker_name, character_name, player_name, rot_name);
}
```

Вот эта инициализация

Comment: Может стоить ограничить инициализацию класса до минимума, чтобы не траттьи много времени и ресурсов?

Comment: Вопрос выглядит как фанатичная преждевременная оптимизация. Скажите пожалуйста, вы столкнулись с проблемой низкой производительности из-за создания нового экземпляра класса?

Comment: Нет, более того. Я сейчас на этапе проектированния.

Comment: @кириллмоисеенков на этапе проектирования нельзя вдаваться в настолько несущественные вопросы реализации. Считаю, что вам стоит забыть о своем вопросе. Если у вас возникнут проблемы с производительностью из-за этого (не представляю как это возможно), то, пожалуйста, задавайте вопрос повторно и прилагайте ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Я лично что-то такое делал, когда стратегии для искусственного интеллекта писал для нашей игры.

Изначально при смене стратегий всегда создавался новый объект. Вроде ничего критичного. Но когда ботов много, если стратегии меняются часто, то уже видны минусы. Проблем ещё добавляет C# с его GC и старой версией моно. Аллокации лучше сократить.

Я бы рекомендовал создавать по экземпляру каждого состояния изначально, а потом менять ссылку на нужное. Это, по личному опыту, намного лучше, чем каждый раз новый объект создавать.